# MySQL and PHP Duplicate Printing

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP and MySQL and am trying to get data from a MySQL table and print it. I make a call to the database and it works great. I am able to read info. out. but there are duplicates in the data.
So far I have:

```
<?php
/// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "loop", "XXX") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("loop") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "profile" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile")
or die(mysql_error());  

//print out info.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo("<pre>");
  var_dump($row);
    echo("</pre>");
}
?>
```

This produces:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(14) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "test@test.com"
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "test@test.com"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "passcode"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(8) "passcode"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["nameFirst"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
    ["nameLast"]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "face.jpg"
    ["pic"]=>
    string(8) "face.jpg"
    [6]=>
    string(16) "Some dummy text."
    ["bio"]=>
    string(16) "Some dummy text."
  }
}
```

Why does it have duplicate elements? I checked the database and it is OK. Can someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: Consider using a newer way such as mysqli.. the answer is the following from php docs : The type of array that is to be fetched. It's a constant and can take the following values: MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, and MYSQL_BOTH. MYSQL_BOTH is default.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a second parameter to mysql_fetch_array function to tell it whether to return an associative array (hashmap - of columns to row values) or a regular array of row elements. By default it will return both.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

There are also dedicated functions to fetch row values as an array and hashmap:
mysql_fetch_row()
mysql_fetch_assoc()

Answer (score 0):

This is because `mysql_fetch_array` returns both numeric and associative array by default check php manual [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Please try to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` because `mysql_fetch_array` was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

but if you still want to use this than this will help

try to pass a second parameter `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` or `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)`